# How to add dependency to configuration in gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm developing Gradle custom plugin. I want to add dependency to the existing configuration. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
open class MyApplicationExtension @Inject constructor(objects: ObjectFactory) {
  val version: Property<String> = objects.property(String::class)
}

class MyApplicationPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
  override fun apply(project: Project) {
    project.plugins.apply(ApplicationPlugin::class)
    val extension = project.extensions.create<MyApplicationExtension>("myApp")
    val implConfig = project.configurations["implementation"]
    implConfig.defaultDependencies {
      add(project.dependencies.create("com:my-app:${extension.version.get()}"))
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to use application in gradle project the added dependency is not added. I'm trying to use it like this:

```
apply<MyApplicationPlugin>()
the<MyApplicationExtension>().version.set("0.1.0")

dependencies {
  // This overrides the default dependencies
  implementation("com:another:0.2.0")
}
```

And when I invoke `dependencies` task my dependency is not shown there. So how to add configurable dependency to the `implementation` configuration from custom plugin? Running with Gradle 5.3.1 in Kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Default dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/5.3.1/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#sec:configuration_defaults) are only used if *no other* dependency is added to the configuration.

Since that does not seem to be your use case, you should simply add the dependency in a normal fashion.

```
implConfig.defaultDependencies {
  add(project.dependencies.create("com:my-app:${extension.version.get()}"))
}
```

needs to become

```
implConfig.dependencies.add(project.dependencies.create("com:my-app:${extension.version.get()}"))
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The value for the extension is not set during the plugin application. It fail with error `No value has been specified for this provider`.

Comment: That seems like a different issue. Hard to confirm without a stacktrace though.